# Simple if statement in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

How do i write an `if` statement in Java that displays `Goodbye!` if the variable `word` contains a letter `d`?

**Thanks to everyone.**

Comment: The documentation is always a good place to start looking: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Check out http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/ for helpful tutorials and http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/ for the Java API.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
if (word.contains("d")) {
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
if(word.indexOf("d") >= 0) {
  System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}
```

Comment: +1 simply because this is the only answer so far that includes the braces.

Comment: should be "... word.indexOf("d") >= 0 ..."

Comment: I believe indexOf('d') would be more efficient than indexOf("d") - note the use of the indexOf method that takes a char instead of a String.

Comment: @Thomas: How would you prove that?

Comment: @Thomas: Parse in a dictionary and find out which one takes longer. ;P

Answer (score 1):

Look up the Java API docs to see what is available in the String class. There are several options including the indexOf() method that returns -1 if the given character is not in the String and an index of the character if it is found in the String.

```
 int ans = mystring.indexOf(mychar);
```

You can then use an if statement to check the ans variable.

Comment: that would be very annoying. In C / C++ not so much, but Java uses booleans.

Comment: @Tom in Java you will have to do if(ans == -1) etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (word.contains("d")) System.out.println("Goodbye!");
```

Well, that was in Java!!

Comment: On what version of java did they introduce the 'contains' method for String?

Answer (score -4):

```
if(word.compareTo("d") == 0)
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");
```

or

```
if(word.equals("d"))
  System.out.println("Goodbye!");
```

That's assuming of course that word is a String and not a char.

Comment: that is wrong, it will compare the whole string, not if it contains "d".

Comment: I read what he was asking incorrectly. I thought he meant he had a String variable named 'word' that he was wanting to check if it's contents was 'd' when he was wanting to find out if a String variables contents had a 'd' in it somewhere. My bad.

-2 haha